# Concat rails variable inside Excel XML View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel

```
<Cell ss:MergeDown="1" ss:StyleID="ce20" ss:Formula=<%= "of:=SUM([.G7:.G#{@nb_days}])" %>><Data ss:Type="Number"></Data></Cell>
```

I'm trying to create this formula using my variable `@nb_days`. It contains a number, such as 31. I've tried several ways but it doesn't work. Either I got a "General output error" at the file opening or the formula is displayed in the cell.

How could I concat the string with the variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:

```
ss:Formula="<%= "=SUM([.I7:.I#{@nb_days}])" %>"
```

Comment: I know, but it says I need to wait 2 days to mark my answer. So wait I will.